# analysis for "such as"

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

> When once more alone, I reviewed the information I had got; looked
>   into my heart, examined its thoughts and feelings, and endeavoured to
>   bring back with a strict hand **such as** had been straying through
>   imagination’s boundless and trackless waste, into the safe fold of
>   common sense. (Jane Eyre)

Is ‘such’ a pronoun, indicating ‘its thoughts and feelings’?
Is ‘as’ a relative modifying ‘such’?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I ... endeavoured to bring back ... such as had been straying*
>
> Is ‘such’ a pronoun, indicating ‘its thoughts and feelings’? Is ‘as’ a relative modifying ‘such’?

I think you've got it. This use of *such as* must be distinguished from its ordinary use to mean *like* or *for example*, where the phrase acts as a complex preposition.

This use of *as* as a relativizer is dying today in formal English, if not quite dead; it has generally been replaced by *that*. It probably lingers with *such* only because of the associated collocation *such as*. However, it is still employed in dialect; I have heard and read it in British dialogue, and in my own native dialect you very frequently heard things like *That's something as I don't like to hear* or *Give it to them as have need of it*.

Answer (score 4):

> “Is ‘such’ a pronoun, indicating ‘its thoughts and feelings’?”

Yes, in part.  The phrase “to bring back with a strict hand such as had been straying” means  “to bring back with a strict hand those that had been straying”, so *such* does not refer to all of Jane's thoughts and feelings, but only those straying too far afield.  In the equivalent “those that”, *[those](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/those#Determiner)* is a <del>determiner</del>† [demonstrative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonstrative_pronoun) and *[that](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/that#Pronoun)* is a relative pronoun, and in  “[such](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/such#Pronoun) as” similar roles are played, respectively.

† When I wrote *determiner* I was thinking of *those* as used in the less-elliptical phrasing “those thoughts and feelings that”, where (I think) it acts as a determiner.  As StoneyB points out, in the phrase *those that* itself, *those* is a demonstrative pronoun.