# use of “such as” in a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality

Is use of "such as" in the following sentences correct grammatically and conceptually?

> The secondary flow loss is due to interaction between vortices and
>   boundary layer of suction and hub surfaces, **such as** tip leakage and
>   hose-shoe vortices, in Wells turbine.

Comment: That is a complex English for me. I am grateful that guide me more about my quastion

Comment: We hope you read and understand the question and answer at the above link (the link is also [**here.**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4191/analysis-for-such-as)) It should make the usage clear.

Comment: The phrase "such as" is introducing examples of what has already been explained. Its meaning is pretty much the same as "for example" but it cannot always be used as a direct replacement.

Comment: @Mick The dupe question resulted in good answers to this question.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I disagree. They are rather technical and, frankly, I began to lose the will to live whilst trying to read them. The level of English used would be appropriate in EL&U, perhaps.

Comment: @Mick Really? I don't find StoneyB's answer stultifying in the least.

Comment: @P.E.Dant The problem is that the questioner demonstrated a good knowledge of English grammar so he was answered at an appropriate level. In particular, he knew what a *relativizer*  was. I couldn't explain what a relativizer is, and I've been using English for more than 60 years. Perhaps this questioner has similar problems. Horses for courses, old chap. It would be good to see an answer here that is pitched at an English *improver*, if not an absolute beginner.

Answer (score 1):

The usage of **such as** is correct in detailing examples used in your passage.

Alternatives for

> **such as**
>   interaction ..., *such as* tip leakage and hose-shoe vortices,...

can be

> **for example**
>   interaction ..., *for example* tip leakage and hose-shoe vortices,...
>
> **like**
>   interaction ..., *like* tip leakage and hose-shoe vortices,...

without lose of understanding or meaning.

Also, I think your sentence should read

> The secondary flow loss is due to interaction**s, such as tip leakage and hose-shoe vortices**, between vortices and **the suction and hub surface** boundary layer in **a** Wells turbine.

the original placement of the **such as** clause seemed awkward.

Comment: That's better. Much better. Even I understand it.